# Input of symbols in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There's an EditText in fragment. User should input a number here (format of input is numeric). But there's a problem: nothing is shown in editText. User can input, but doesn't see the number. What's the matter?

Xml of fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalculatorFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculator_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/weight"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/height"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/height"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/count"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/count"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code of fragment:

```
package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;
    EditText eWeight, eHeight;
    int nWeight, nHeight;

    public CalculatorFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);
        Button button = v.findViewById(R.id.count);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                eWeight = v.findViewById(R.id.weight);
                eHeight = v.findViewById(R.id.height);
                nWeight = Integer.parseInt(eWeight.getText().toString());
                nHeight = Integer.parseInt(eHeight.getText().toString());
                if (nWeight-nHeight<100) {
                    textView.setText("Normal weight");
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Actually I think that emulator can cause this problem, because when I input numbers, I can change the position of cursor, that's why there's something here. But it's not shown. But at the same time when I try to parse to int information from this editTexts, it cause an error as there's nothing here.

Comment: Does it occur only when input type is number?

Comment: @aomerk, no, it occures with any type

Comment: can you please share style.xml file

Comment: @aomerk I refreshed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the codes you've provided, there was a problem with the layout. Just add this line to your EditText xml block: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of hard fixing it to `20dp`, which is not considered as a good dimension of height for EditText field.

As per Google Android developer suggestions, the minimum height for an EditText should be `50dp`. So you may also consider changing the height of EditText to `50dp` also instead of `"wrap_content"`

---

Thus the modified xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalculatorFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculator_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/weight"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/height"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/height"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/count"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/count"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```